# Checking multiple checkboxes for numerc input vb.net / windows forms application

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox, numeric

I have a form with 30 (currently) textboxes where a user will enter data. I need to restrict the user to numerical input only into each textbox, preferably before shifting focus to the next textbox.

Thanks to the internet I have found a piece of code that does this for an individual box. I want to avoid repeating this code 30 times if at all possible.

I see many answers referring to the error provider, but I'm not really clear on how to incorporate this into my code.

Could someone please take pity on me and show me an easy way of achieving my goal ? My head is spinning from all the posts I've read that nearly-but-not-quite answer my question.

Thankyou in anticipation

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The following code restricts the input of a TextBox to numeric characters, arrow keys, back, clear and tab, as well as "-" and (exactly one) decimal point.

To avoid repeating the code 30 times, all you need to do is add another sub similar to `Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()`, where you replace all occurences of TextBox1 by the name of one of your TextBoxes until you have one such sub for each TextBox.

```
Public WithEvents NumericTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Set NumericTextBox = TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub NumericTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyLeft, _
         vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab 

    Case Asc("-")
      If Instr(1, NumericTextBox.Text, "-") > 0 Or NumericTextBox.SelStart > 0 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
      End If

    Case Asc(".")
      If InStr(1, NumericTextBox.Text, ".") > 0 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
      End If

    Case Else
      KeyAscii = 0
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again Ben. Sorry, should have been more specific. The problem is I'm getting the following error 'vbkey0' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level. this error repeats for every vbkey. Also, Type 'MSForms.ReturnInteger' is not defined and Type 'MSForms.Textbox' is not defined. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here and there's an impending facepalm waiting for me. Thanks for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below link

[Accept only integer value](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/127299/textbox-validation)

```
    Public WithEvents textbox As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Set NumericTextBox = TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub textbox _KeyPress(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs
)
  If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48) _
              Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
            e.Handled = True
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
            e.Handled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou Pradnya for the elegant solution. Do you have an equally efficient way of repeating this for 30 textboxes without retyping it for textbox2_keypress, textbox3_keypress etc etc. That's the crux of my problem now.

Comment: I edit above code you can try it ...and as BEN said you can add another sub similar to Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()...
I hope it work for your project..

Answer (score 0):

Something I wrote today. Copy and paste it into a new class file, and be sure to import `InputVerification` where it's used.

```
Public Class InputVerification
Private ctrlArray As Control()
Private fltArray As String()
Private retMsg As String()

Public Property Case_Insensitive As Boolean

Public Const Yes As Boolean = True
Public Const No As Boolean = False

Public Sub New()
    Case_Insensitive = True
End Sub
''' <summary>
''' Returns a value if InputFilter returns False.
''' </summary>
''' <value>Nothing.</value>
''' <returns>The offending control name and character, in a String array.</returns>

Public Property Return_Message As String()
    Get
        Return retMsg
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        retMsg = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' The controls to be checked for valid input.
''' </summary>
''' <value>Any control type with a .Text property.</value>
''' <returns>An array with all the controls specified.</returns>

Public Property Controls() As Control()
    Get
        Return ctrlArray
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Control())
        ctrlArray = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' The characters to be allowed.
''' </summary>
''' <value>Any ASCII value.</value>
''' <returns>A String array for each control specified.</returns>

Public Property Filter() As String()
    Get
        Return fltArray
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        fltArray = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Checks to see if the characters entered match the valid characters.
''' Usage: {1, "a-d", 3, "0-5", "e-g", "?"}
''' The number defines how many filters for that control, in order.
''' </summary>
''' <returns>A boolean value.</returns>
''' <remarks>Use Return_Message, if this fails. First a number to define
''' the number of filters for that control. The next are as many filters
''' as you defined.</remarks>

Public Function InputFilter() As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim numFilters As Integer = 0
    Dim oldPosition As Integer = 0
    Dim newPosition As Integer = 0
    Dim convValidChars As New Collection
    For Each cntrl As Control In Controls
        convValidChars.Clear()
        oldPosition = newPosition
        numFilters = Filter(newPosition)
        newPosition = newPosition + numFilters
        For k As Integer = oldPosition To newPosition
            If Filter(k).ToString.Contains("-") And Filter(k).ToString.Length > 1 Then
                Dim split() As String = Filter(k).ToString.Split("-"c)
                Dim lowest, highest As Integer
                If AscW(split(0).ToString) > AscW(split(1).ToString) Then
                    lowest = AscW(split(1))
                    highest = AscW(split(0))
                Else
                    lowest = AscW(split(0))
                    highest = AscW(split(1))
                End If
                For j As Integer = lowest To highest
                    convValidChars.Add(j)
                Next

            Else
                convValidChars.Add(AscW(Filter(k)))
            End If
        Next
        Dim matchFound As Boolean = False
        For Each indvUCC In cntrl.Text
            For Each indvVC In convValidChars
                matchFound = False
                Dim indvUCCINT As Integer = Asc(indvUCC)
                If indvVC = indvUCCINT Then
                    matchFound = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If Case_Insensitive = True Then
                        If indvUCCINT >= 65 AndAlso indvUCCINT <= 90 Then
                            indvUCCINT = Asc(indvUCC.ToString.ToLower)
                        ElseIf indvUCCINT >= 97 AndAlso indvUCCINT <= 122 Then
                            indvUCCINT = Asc(indvUCC.ToString.ToUpper)
                        End If
                        If indvVC = indvUCCINT Then
                            matchFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If matchFound = False Then
                Dim txtbox = TryCast(cntrl, TextBox)
                If txtbox IsNot Nothing Then
                    txtbox.Focus()
                    txtbox.SelectAll()
                End If
                Return_Message = {cntrl.Name, indvUCC}
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        newPosition += 1
    Next
    Return True
End Function
End Class
```

Example usage:

```
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Form1.InputVerification

    Public Class test
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim filter_Test As New InputVerification
            filter_Test.Controls = {TextBox1, TextBox2}
            filter_Test.Filter = {2, "a-z", "0-9", 1, "0-9"}
            filter_Test.Case_Insensitive = Yes
            If filter_Test.InputFilter() = False Then
                Dim respCTRL As String = filter_Test.Return_Message(0)
                Dim respChar As String = filter_Test.Return_Message(1)
                MsgBox("Control " & respCTRL & " has an invalid character, which is " & respChar)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I have it far better written up here, as it's a bit confusing to use at first.

[InputVerification Thread](http://www.overclock.net/t/1565152/input-verification-function#post_24175589)

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I'll have a look at this.

Comment: What's strange is that this code worked wonderfully when I posted it, but was completely broken a day or so ago. I updated the post with the correct one.